# how to create a tag by traversing attributes from another tag in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

input xml :

```
<content>
    <link>
        <text>sign on</text>
        <trackableReference local="/PUBLIC_WEB_URL" title=""/>
    </link>
</content>
```

output xml:

```
<content>
    <a id="mylink" href="PUBLIC_WEB_URL" title="">sign on</a>
</content>
```

xslt's tried which works fine for this:

1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="content">
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[name()='link']">
        <a id="mylink">
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="trackableReference/@local"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="trackableReference/@title"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="content">
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[name()='link']">
        <a id="mylink">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name()='trackableReference'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@local"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="title">
                <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name()='trackableReference'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name()='text'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But  I have a scenario where I have to create some global variables in template whose values are to be dynamically modified according to the child nodes traversed. Example consider above the template modified in this scenario

```
<xsl:template match="*[name()='link']">
    <xsl:variable name="x1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="x2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="x3"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name()='trackableReference'">
                <xsl:value-of select="@local"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="name()='text'">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <a id="mylink">
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="$x1"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="$x2"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$x3"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Here

- `x1` variable should be assiged with value selected from `@local`,
- `x2` variable should be assiged with value selected from `@title`,
- `x3` variable should be assiged with value selected from `'text'` node.

So I would like to get these variables declared on top to be assigned with values extracted from child nodes traversed. I got stuck here and cannot move forward.

Can anyone resolve this problem.

Comment: This question leaves the reader guessing. If you show us a complete (as small as possible) XML document and the complete wanted result from it and explain the requirements for the transformation, then many people would be able to show how to do this. And of course, XSLT is a functional language and any idea to initially define a variable and later change its value are unrealistic -- such thing is impossible in a functional language. Of course, there *is* a way to do do the same transformation *without* variable update.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you must use variables, but here's an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="link">
        <xsl:variable name="x1" select="trackableReference/@local"/>
        <xsl:variable name="x2" select="trackableReference/@title"/>
        <xsl:variable name="x3" select="text"/>
        <a id="mylink" href="{$x1}" title="{$x2}">          
            <xsl:value-of select="$x3" />           
        </a>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you don't really need variables, you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <a id="mylink" href="{trackableReference/@local}" title="{trackableReference/@title}">          
        <xsl:value-of select="text" />          
    </a>        
</xsl:template>
```

Also, I noticed you said:

> create some global variables in template whose values are to be
>   dynamically modified

This is not possible. Variables cannot change value once set.

Comment: :I did the same in the first xslt(1) which works for the above scenario,what actually I need is i will create some variables at the top and set these variables according the value extracted from the child node.Like in above example x1 needs to be set to value extracted from '@local' as extracted from <xsl:for-each>

Comment: @Jeevan - Since variables cannot be modified once they're initialized the only way you could do that is to add an `xsl:for-each` to every `xsl:variable`. You can't have an `xsl:variable` and then set it's value in a later `xsl:for-each` (or any other way).

Comment: Is it so. Now i have to declare a variable and inside the varaible declaration i have to work around the value extraction to be done and set to it right.

Comment: some thing like this.                                                                  <xsl:variable name="t"><xsl:for-each select="child::*"><xsl:if test="name()='text'"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each></xsl:variable>                                                    its very painful to do.

Comment: @Jeevan - Yes that would be painful, but it's not clear why you need to do the `xsl:for-each`. It could most likely be solved with a different xpath in the select. Maybe you could update your examples with a better example of why you're relying on `xsl:for-each`?

Comment: actually I implemented the  xpath expressions that you have suggested for my original xml document before(part of it is shared in example)  but somehow iam unable to see the extracted values in final output. so have to opt for <xsl:foreach>.                                                      anyways thanks for the precious inputs given.